# Haskell printing file line by line

Tags: file, haskell, printing

EDIT: New code added and new errors changed too. It compiles!

I am a newbie to Haskell, and am running into a problem in a code I'm trying to create for printing lines from a text file. In doing this, I would need the output of the file to list the lines one by one and number them, and put a row of dashes between lines that don't start with the same character. Here is an example of the output I want:

```
$runghc group.hs (file I input)
1 able
2 academia
3 algae
------
4 carton
------
5 fairway
------
6 hex
7 hockshop
```

And here is the code that I have currently. I think I'm approaching this from the right direction, but I am running into some errors.

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

group :: [Char] -> [Char]
group file = printSplit (words (show file)) 1

printSplit (x:[]) n = show n ++ x 
printSplit (x:t) n
       | head x == head (head t) = ((show n) ++ x) ++ printSplit t (n+1)
       | otherwise = ((show n) ++ x ++ "\n------") ++ printSplit t (n+1)

main = do
 args <- getArgs
 bytes <- readFile (head args)
 putStrLn (group bytes)
```

I am running into this error:

```
*Main> main
1"able\nacademia\nalgae\ncarton\nfairway\nhex\nhockshop\n"
```

And don't quite yet know how to do with this...

---

ORIGINAL POST INFO: A different way I'm attempting is to do words (show file) which will give me

```
["able","academia","algae","carton","fairway","hex","hockshop"]
```

But I'm not sure where to go after that. And since I'm trying to learn higher-order functions, maybe someone could explain how to use map or fold to try these to me if possible? :)

Comment: Use type signatures, please. It would have made at least the first error message much less confusing, and the code becomes more readable.

Comment: I have added a type signature and updated the code! :)

Comment: @user3290526: How is the file structured? A single word in every line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `n` in a concatenation, GHC assumes that `n` is a `[Char]`. However, you want `n` to be an `Int` or something similar and use `show n` whenever you want to transform it to a `String`.

The other error has to do with the return of `group`. Since `group` is just `printSplit` with some fixed parameters, it has the same return type, which is `[String]` or `[[Char]]`. However, `putStrLn` expects a single String. You can use `unlines` or `concat` in order to concatenate your strings.

Comment: I have updated the code, and see what you mean. I've changed the implementation, but can you try to help me figure out these two errors? :)